# NEED HELP! How to build Ghostscript with trapping enabled? ENABLE_TRAPPING

Tags: linux, makefile, ghostscript

How can I build Ghostscript with ENABLE_TRAPPING?

In docs it says "build with ENABLE_TRAPPING", but what does it mean?

When I execute "make ENABLE_TRAPPING" it returns "no rules for creating target "ENABLE_TRAPPING"" (it's okay).

But when I use "make ENABLE_TRAPPING=1" it compiles good, but the example in docs `gs -sDEVICE=psdcmyk -dTrapX=2 -dTrapY=2 -o out.psd -c "<< /TrapOrder [ 4 5 3 1 0 2 ] >> setpagedevice" -f examples/tiger.eps` doesn't work: artifacts instead of tiger image.

In addition, when trying to change Makefile (decomment $(PSD)trapping.dev and other actions), make returns compilation errors.

So how can I do it?

Makefile: `https://pastebin.com/QVTw5bqK`

Comment: Without seeing the makefile I can only guess but you might want to try `make ENABLE_TRAPPING=1` .

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, here is the Makefile. I have also tried =1, it compiles, but the example `gs -sDEVICE=psdcmyk -dTrapX=2 -dTrapY=2 -o out.psd -c "<< /TrapOrder [ 4 5 3 1 0 2 ] >> setpagedevice" -f examples\tiger.eps` not working.

Comment: Trapping is enabled by default, you should not have to make any changes to the makefile.  Even if you did need to, 'ENABLE_TRAPPING' would be a target and make is properly telling you there is no such target, that's not how you wold enable it even if you had to. So, apparently your real problem; In what way 'not working' ?

Comment: I changed the description, see it.
I read that trapping is disabled by default due to problems with patents.
The example doesn't work 'cause there are artifacts instead of tiger picture in out.psd.

Comment: Then you are either using old code (> 2.5 years old) or have read the wrong document. In  ghostpdl/doc/Devices.htm, under Trapping patents it says " We believe that the last of these has now lapsed, and so have enabled the code by default". Your TrapOrder makes no sense for CMYK output, you have specified two spot channels. However even removing that I see the output is incorrect. Not what I would personally describe as 'artifacts', just a dark gray page. You should open a bug report.

Comment: Thank you, it's the solution.

Comment: @KenS Hello. My comment isn't directly related to the question and is about an opinion of a GhostScript developer. I have a problem with viewgif.ps from standard GS 9.54.0. The problem is that `gswin64c.exe -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "-sOutputFile=output.pdf" -f "viewgif.ps" -c "(picture.gif) <</PageSize 2 index viewGIFgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewGIF showpage"` creates a PDF with a picture underscaled to ~10% of the page's area. Can I fit my gif to a PDF page size or I need to report a bug on GS bugtracker? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796136/

Comment: Since I don't have your input file I can't possibly comment. If you think there's a bug then I'd open a bug report.

Comment: @KenS Thank you for your interest. I opened standard Hydrangeas.jpg from Windows 7 in MS Paint and saved it as Hydrangeas.gif, which stood for picture.gif here. I filed a bug as well: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=703904 Is Hydrangeas.jpg available at your side? Regards.

Comment: @KenS https://windowswallpaper.miraheze.org/wiki/File:Hydrangeas_(Windows_7).jpg#file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KenS told me, it's said in the documentation "We believe that the last of these has now lapsed, and so have enabled the code by default".
The example in same documentation can be incorrect.