# Automatic conversion of a hundred pictures to PDF in Ghostscript works with JPG but fails with GIF

Tags: batch-file, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to resolve a problem of converting of a few hundreds pictures to a single PDF by means of bare GhostScript on Windows. Surprisingly, there were no solutions on SO to do so automatically.
So I wrote a batch to convert a whole folder with JPG and GIF to a sole PDF, regardless of the amount of pictures which are contained in that folder.

```
@ECHO OFF

goto comment1
        A script to convert a whole folder of GIF and JPG files to PDF
        by means of bare GhostScript. It works with several hundreds of files.

        Prerequisites: One has to put gsdll64.dll, gswin64c.exe, viewgif.ps
        and viewjpeg.ps from GhostScript installation folder
        into the folder containing this script. Launched, this
        script converts any .jpg and .gif files lying in the same folder into
        a single PDF. Tested with GhostScript 9.54.0. For some cause, GIF files
        require to pass g768x1024 option to GS executable, where 768 stands for
        the width of a GIF and 1024 stands for the height of it. JPG files work
        without this option, though.
:comment1

if not exist "gsdll64.dll" echo gsdll64.dll not found && pause && exit
if not exist "gswin64c.exe" echo gswin64c.exe not found && pause && exit
if not exist "viewgif.ps" echo viewgif.ps not found && pause && exit
if not exist "viewjpeg.ps" echo viewjpeg.ps not found && pause && exit

set A=
set i=
set c=
set d=
set e=
set f=
set tempFilename=
set tempFilenamePattern=
set bufferFilename=
SET _result=
SET fileExtension=

set x=%random%
set y=0
:loopToCreateRandomlyNamedTempFileToPrependOutputPDF
set /a y+=1 
set "tempFilename=%x%_%y%.pdf"
if exist %tempFilename% goto loopToCreateRandomlyNamedTempFileToPrependOutputPDF
set "tempFilenamePattern=%tempFilename%"
set "tempFilename="

set u=%random%
set w=0
:loopToCreateRandomlyNamedBufferFileToAbsorbTempFileAndOutputPDF
set /a w+=1 
set "bufferFilename=%u%_%w%.pdf"
if "%bufferFilename%" == "%tempFilename%" goto loopToCreateRandomlyNamedBufferFileToAbsorbTempFileAndOutputPDF
if exist %bufferFilename% goto loopToCreateRandomlyNamedBufferFileToAbsorbTempFileAndOutputPDF

goto comment2
        For some cause, if MaximalLengthOfGSStringInWindows has been set to 
        the values exceeding 1600-2500 (and bigger), GhostScript fails with "Command too long"
        on large amount of pictures (30 files or so).
:comment2
SET MaximalLengthOfGSStringInWindows=1500

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "optionToFitPDFPageDimensionsToJPGSize= <</PageSize 2 index viewJPEGgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewJPEG showpage"
set "optionToFitPDFPageDimensionsToGIFSize= <</PageSize 2 index viewGIFgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewGIF showpage"

set "scrollingPDFViewOption=  [ /PageMode /UseNone /Page 1 /View [ /Fit ] /PageLayout /OneColumn /DOCVIEW pdfmark  "
set "LosslessPDFMergingOption=-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode"

set currentCnt=
set totalCnt=
set "Newvar="

for /f %%A in ('dir ".\*.jpg" ".\*.gif" /a:-d /o:n /b') do set /a totalCnt+=1

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir ".\*.jpg" ".\*.gif" /a:-d /o:n /b') do (
    set /a currentCnt+=1
    set "fileExtension=%%i"
    if !fileExtension:~-3!==gif call set "Newvar=%%Newvar%%(%%i) !optionToFitPDFPageDimensionsToGIFSize!  "
    if !fileExtension:~-3!==jpg call set "Newvar=%%Newvar%%(%%i) !optionToFitPDFPageDimensionsToJPGSize!  "
    call :check
)
exit /b

:check
CALL SET _result="!Newvar!"

set "resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr=!_result:~%MaximalLengthOfGSStringInWindows%!"

if not !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ . if %currentCnt% equ 1 (
echo Error at the first iteration: analyzed string exceeds MaximalLengthOfGSStringInWindows
pause
exit
)

goto comment3
        _result and Newvar contain the list of pictures plus options to be processed by Ghostscript.

        The for loop here is an "artifical" construction which is iterated only once. Its aim is
        just to pass _result to Ghostscript to create "output.pdf"

        `if not !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ .` checks whether _result variable
        exceeds 1500 symbols. If `if not !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ .` is true,
        then _result exceeds 1500 symbols and cannot be processed in one pass because of
        possible "Command too long" GhostScript error when merging. Hence, right after the creation
        of an intermediate PDF file, this `if` branch resets _result and Newvar so that
        future iterations of :check subroutine wouldn't process the files we deal with at
        the current :check iteration.

        The `if not defined tempFilename` sub-branch checks if there is an intermediate PDF filename which
        might have been created at past iterations. If there's no such a filename, then we set it
        and rename the intermediate PDF, which we have created in parental `if` under "output.pdf" name,
        to the tempfilename.
        If an intermediate PDF exists, then we get into `else` branch and merge it with "output.pdf"
        created in parental `if`. In the newly created "bufferFilename" PDf, tempfilename becomes a "head",
        and output.pdf becomes a "tail". Then we replace the old tempfile with the newly created.

        `if %currentCnt% equ %totalCnt%` branch is cosmetic. It's executed only once, at the very last
        iteration, to make sure that the file containing all processed pictures is named "output.pdf".
:comment3

if not !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ . (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%c in ('set _result') do ( 
        start /b /wait "" "%cd%\gswin64c.exe" -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g768x1024 "-sOutputFile=%cd%\output.pdf" -f "%cd%\viewgif.ps" -f "%cd%\viewjpeg.ps" -c %%d -c "%scrollingPDFViewOption%"   
    )

    call set _result=
    call set Newvar=
    if not defined tempFilename (
        set "tempFilename=!tempFilenamePattern!"
        rename output.pdf !tempFilename!
    ) else (
        start /b /wait "" "%cd%\gswin64c.exe" -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -o %bufferFilename% %LosslessPDFMergingOption% !tempFilename! output.pdf
        del /f /s /q !tempFilename!
        rename %bufferFilename% !tempFilename!

        if %currentCnt% equ %totalCnt% (
            del /f /s /q output.pdf
            rename !tempFilename! output.pdf
        )
    )
)

goto comment4

        `if !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ . if %currentCnt% equ %totalCnt%` branch is
        executed only at the vary last iteration in cases where result does not exceed 1500 symbols.

        `if defined tempFilename` branch is identical to `else` branch in comment3.
:comment4

if !resultMinusMaximalLenghtOfWinStr!. equ . if %currentCnt% equ %totalCnt% (

    for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%e in ('set _result') do ( 
        start /b /wait "" "%cd%\gswin64c.exe" -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g768x1024 "-sOutputFile=%cd%\output.pdf" -f "%cd%\viewgif.ps" -f "%cd%\viewjpeg.ps" -c %%f -c "%scrollingPDFViewOption%"   
    )
    if defined tempFilename (
        start /b /wait "" "%cd%\gswin64c.exe" -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -o %bufferFilename% %LosslessPDFMergingOption% !tempFilename! output.pdf
        del /f /s /q !tempFilename!
        rename %bufferFilename% !tempFilename!
        if %currentCnt% equ %totalCnt% (
            del /f /s /q output.pdf
            rename !tempFilename! output.pdf
        )
    )
)

exit /b

goto :eof
```

It works perfectly, I tested both little and large (up to 200) amounts of pictures.
But some problem raised up.

In essence, the conversion of a JPG is done with this command:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g768x1024 "-sOutputFile=output.pdf" -f "viewgif.ps" -f "viewjpeg.ps" -c "(picture.jpg) <</PageSize 2 index viewJPEGgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewJPEG showpage"
```

the conversion of a GIF is done with this command:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g768x1024 "-sOutputFile=output.pdf" -f "viewgif.ps" -f "viewjpeg.ps" -c "(picture.gif) <</PageSize 2 index viewGIFgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewGIF showpage"
```

Both commands correctly work in case all pictures are vertical and have size of 768x1024.

Removal of -g768x1024 parameter breaks the second command (GIF-related) but not the first one.
Without the -g, gif pictures get underscaled down to ~10% of a page square.

Basically, even the following line gives a PDF with an underscaled picture:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "-sOutputFile=output.pdf" -f "viewgif.ps" -c "(picture.gif) <</PageSize 2 index viewGIFgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewGIF showpage"
```

I tried different combinations of  -dPSFitPage, -dEPSFitPage, -dFIXEDMEDIA, but no luck.
The version of GS is 9.54.0

The question:
How can one make GS automatically fit PDF page to the size of a GIF?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=  by replacing with -o

-f is usually placed at the end after -c

Also since a GIF is unit less you need to add a Resolution such as a default of 1/72"

Use

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "output.pdf" "viewgif.ps" -c "(picture.gif) <</PageSize 2 index viewGIFgetsize 2 array astore /HWResolution [ 72 72 ] >> setpagedevice viewGIF showpage"
```

Remember "All of\the paths"  to files, including the resource file "viewgif.ps" need to be defined well, either in path and/or environment.

Comment: I saw that remark on HWresolution from Ray Johnston. I'll post my own answer later.